# restrict columns in dynamic view MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using dynamic view to display and edit the records.

```
@model dynamic
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", null,  FormMethod.Post))
 {
@Html.EditorForModel()

 <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}
<script>
$(".datetime").datetime();
</script>
```

The problem is it displays all the properties of the model object.
Suppose there is a primary key, we dont want to show it on screen.
And another case would be foreign key properties those are being displayed as integer values instead of its descriptions from related tables.

Can somebody advise how can I handle these scenarios in dynamic views?

Comment: I'm curious. Why dynamic rather than strongly-typed?

Comment: The architect decided to have dynamic view, he may use it in certain cases in future though we are in initial stages of development. My task is to implement those.:)

Comment: great architect in my dynamic view

Comment: You should really question the "architect", sounds like he doesn't know what he is talking about. However, you can probably use editor templates, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx.

Comment: The phrase "he may use it in certain cases in future" rings all kinds of alarms. Write code you *do* need, not code you *might eventually* need. Chances are that [you aren't gonna need it](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt).